# JAXB Customizations - Multiple schemas inside WSDL and schemaLocation

Tags: wsdl, jaxb

I have a WSDL which contains 3 schemas inside it's "types" element. The schemas are not defined in external XSDs but inside the types element.

I want to customize an element inside schema number 2 and change it's name to avoid a conflict.

So in the schemaLocation how can I do that? Despite making the question I have the way to do this:

```
 schemaLocation="../wsdl-files/mywsdl.wsdl#types?schema2">
     ...
     <jxb:bindings node="some xpath
```

but I am not the one who found it but a colleague of mine who is not working with me anymore. Is there a resource where I can find the explanation for it even if I understand it? A link or a book? Somewhere where I can find also other examples.

My problem is the schemaLocation value(../wsdl-files/mywsdl.wsdl#types?schema2) not the xpath. I want to know all the possibilities to reference a schema inside a WSDL. I need a documentation for this or something.

Thank you very much

Comment: My problem is the schemaLocation value(../wsdl-files/mywsdl.wsdl#types?schema2) not the xpath etc. I want to know all the possibilities to reference a schema inside a WSDL etc. I need a documentation for this or something.

Thanks again

Comment: What tool are you using to bind the WSDL?

Comment: you should edit your question and put the contents of your comment into it as an "Update:" section. Then delete the comment.

Comment: The syntax you gave for specifying a schema inside a WSDL file is horrible - but it works! In CXF, I was able to do XPATH-based node access using a suffix of `#types6`, where the schema in question was the 6th in the file. SCD as suggested by skaffman indeed works much better, but you've helped me solve this particular problem, so many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JAXB Ri v2.1 added support for [Schema Component Designators][1], which in theory allow you to reference schema components symbolically, rather than by their file location and xpath location. In principle, this is much nicer to use, but I've never used it myself.

I'm not sure how widely supported this is, however. There's very little mention of it anywhere else other than that blog entry. It does mention it was part of the proposed spec for JAXB 2.1, so if that was passed, it should be implemented by every JAXB 2.1 implementation, including Java6. It's possible, though, that it was never actually added to the spec.

Comment: Thanks man! That looks great.
But do you have anything that describes these:
#types?schema2

Thanks!

Comment: @DaUltimateTrooper: The point of SCD is that you don't need to specify the schema location in the binding customization, you refer to the schema elements by name.

Comment: From what I found, SCD is still not officially supported, but Sun's xjc will use it if given the `-extension` option, and dependent tools like CXF work with it as well. The syntax is even harder to grok than XPATH but it can be made to work.

Answer (score 2):

Had similar problem (five schemas in types with common names) and somehow didn't get SCD to work correctly. My solution was following:

custombinding.xml:

```
<jxb:bindings version="2.1" 
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="file:wsdlfile.wsdl" node="*/xs:schema[1]">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package  name="my.custom.package"/>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

xjc call in ant build file:

```
<target name="xjc_generate">
    <exec executable="xjc" >
      <arg value="-wsdl" />
      <arg value="${wsdl.base}/service/wsdlfile.wsdl" />
      <arg value="-d" />
      <arg value="${dir.src}" />
      <arg value="-b" />
      <arg value="${wsdl.base}/service/custombinding.xjb" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the location of the schema in the wsdl like this - if this is the 2nd schema.

> e.g: mywsdl.wsdl#types2
>   If the 10th then mywsdl.wsdl#types10

Hope it helps someone.

```
  <jxb:bindings version="2.1" 
        xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

        <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../wsdl-files/mywsdl.wsdl#types2" node="/xs:schema">
            <jxb:schemaBindings>
                <jxb:package  name="my.custom.package"/>
            </jxb:schemaBindings>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
```